# change default name of primary key in workbench

Tags: mysql, settings, workbench

I just switched over to workbench to manage mySQL. Every time i create a new table and name it I get an attribute primary key with a name of idTableName I would like to change it to: id_TableName or TableName_id so it fits my convention better. 
Is that possible??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here about how to change primary-key naming scheme with MySQL Workbench.

Navigate to Edit -> Preferences -> and move to Model tab.

[image: MySql workbench - table pk naming scheme change]

Answer (score 2):

For changing the name of the default primary key name you can

go to Edit - > Preferences - > Model change the value of PK Name under Column defaults